# html5 audio tag how to add src?

Tags: directory, root, html5-audio, set-difference

I'm new to `HTML5`. I used an audio tag of HTML5 in my page. I want to add the source of my **mp3** file from different root folder. My root folder is `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/App/` but I want to use folder from `D:/Web/mp3`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for HTML5 audio tag is...

```
<audio src="/audio/mp3/someAudioFile" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
```

where "/audio/mp3/someAudioFile" is an example relative URL from where your audio file can be accessed. Basically, in this example, I am assuming that you will map to map your "D:/web" folder to "/audio" within your IIS (it can be mapped to whatever you choose to).

A quick google search of "HTML5 audio tag" will get you much more information but for starters, you can refer to
http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: Can you tell me how to map IIS or tell me the link?

Comment: @Norak Here is a link to another StackOverflow question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497131/iis-virtual-directory-map-to-network-drive-with-drive-letter-but-fail-to-creat - this might help you. One unsolicited advise: if you are not comfortable with IIS configuration, I would recommend that you get your security aspects reviewed by some expert before exposing your server on the Internet!

Comment: I use it only on Localhost. It's just a back office. Thank you for your advice.