# File storage solution for applications on multiple servers with the possibility of directly serving them

Tags: asp.net, file, infrastructure

Instances of two ASP.Net web applications are deployed on different servers in a server farm setup. Session and data is shared between them by using a common database.

However I also need to share files between these applications for the following purpose:

- Users should be able to upload files from each type and instance of an application
- These files should appear as links to the users of both types of application
- The files should be downloadable

The files can be Word or PDF documents but also company logos, that should be referenced from external webpages.

SQL Server FileStreams or Microsoft's Distributed File System do not solve the problem of directly serving the files.

How do I directly offer the content of these files to a web-request? Is there an already existing solution?
Is it possible to have a solution that resides inside of the hosting environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a virtual directory in IIS mapped to a network share.

[IIS Virtual Directory map to network drive (with drive letter) but fail to create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497131/iis-virtual-directory-map-to-network-drive-with-drive-letter-but-fail-to-creat)